# Facebook graph API does not return all the pages associated with an account

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My Facebook account has access to two business pages, each of them connected to respective Instagram accounts. The goal here is to get the Instagram business account id as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started#getting-started. In step 4, to get the accounts I'm hitting the `GET /me/accounts` endpoint and only getting one out of the two pages that I am part of.

[Only received one page, instead of two that I have access to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etWeH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.